# Why does FineUploader's template/default.html look for files in the client folder?

Tags: fine-uploader

Why does FineUploader's template/default.html look for files in the client folder? When you follow the set up instructions on their website you are left with something that looks like this:

```
root@UbuntuVM:/usr/local/nginx/html/example.com/wwwroot# ls
0.0.0.0                   fine-uploader-gallery.css      placeholders
all.fine-uploader.js      fine-uploader-gallery.min.css  processing.gif
all.fine-uploader.min.js  fine-uploader.min.css          retry.gif
composer.json             fine-uploader-new.css          template.html
composer.lock             fine-uploader-new.min.css      templates
composer.phar             iframe.xss.response.js         trash.gif
continue.gif              LICENSE                        vendor
edit.gif                  loading.gif
fine-uploader.css         pause.gif
```

And in the template folder there is a default.html file that looks for client/fine-uploader.js. I followed the instructions - why is the default template not working?

Answer (score 0):

The Fine Uploader HTML templates serve as a starting point for your web app. It is expected that you make appropriate adjustments based on the location of your resources and your desired look and feel.

Comment: How can I get a working demo up and running using the template file?

Comment: Have a look at the getting started guides at http://docs.fineuploader.com. Summary: 1. Create a server to handle request and serve up the static resources. 2. Adjust client-side paths/code accordingly.

Comment: You'll need to find a web developer with basic knowledge of html, js, and perhaps php to help you out then. Fine Uploader is a JavaScript library that is meant to be implemented by developers with at least basic web development and server side knowledge. It sounds like you may be lacking these skills.